# How can callbacks with captured mutable variables be treated like normal mutable borrows?

Tags: callback, rust

`Foo` can be modified using the method `.modify()`:

```
struct Foo;
impl Foo {
    fn modify(&mut self) {}
}
```

`Bar` stores a callback:

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    callback: Box<FnMut() + 'a>,
}
impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn new<F: FnMut() + 'a>(f: F) -> Bar<'a> {
        Bar {
            callback: Box::new(f),
        }
    }
}
```

`init()` takes a slice of `Bar` and executes their callbacks:

```
fn init(bars: &mut [Bar]) {
    for b in bars {
        (*b.callback)();
    }
}
```

And now the most interesting:

Changing `Foo` in a loop works fine; on each iteration of the loop `foo` is mutably borrowed and `.modify()` is called:

```
fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo;

    for _ in 0..10 {
        foo.modify();
    }
}
```

Changing `Foo` inside of the callbacks does not work:

```
fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo;

    let mut bar1 = Bar::new(|| foo.modify());
    let mut bar2 = Bar::new(|| foo.modify());

    init(&mut [bar1, bar2]);
}
```

[Try it on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dc51a0408bd67eaf9f9500b5c0cfc536&version=stable&backtrace=0), 
it has an error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `foo` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:27:29
   |
26 |     let mut bar1 = Bar::new(|| foo.modify());
   |                             -- --- previous borrow occurs due to use of `foo` in closure
   |                             |
   |                             first mutable borrow occurs here
27 |     let mut bar2 = Bar::new(|| foo.modify());
   |                             ^^ --- borrow occurs due to use of `foo` in closure
   |                             |
   |                             second mutable borrow occurs here
...
30 | }
   | - first borrow ends here
```

How to implement a similar guarantee for item 2?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html):

```
let foo = RefCell::new(Foo);

{
    let bar1 = Bar::new(|| foo.borrow_mut().modify());
    let bar2 = Bar::new(|| foo.borrow_mut().modify());
    init(&mut [bar1, bar2]);
}

let mut foo = foo.into_inner(); // extract foo to use in external API
```

Be careful with `borrow_mut()`, it panics if the value is currently borrowed.

---

If you can change `Bar` and `init()`, you can pass value `foo` to the `init()` separate from the method `modify()`:

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    callback: Box<FnMut(&mut Foo) + 'a>,
}
impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn new<F: FnMut(&mut Foo) + 'a>(f: F) -> Bar<'a> {
        Bar {
            callback: Box::new(f),
        }
    }
}

fn init(bars: &mut [Bar], arg: &mut Foo) {
    for b in bars {
        (*b.callback)(arg);
    }
}
```

```
let mut bar1 = Bar::new(|x| x.modify());
let mut bar2 = Bar::new(Foo::modify); // you can pass it without closure
init(&mut [bar1, bar2], &mut foo);
```

Comment: The problem is that `Foo` is an public user API.

Comment: You do not need to modify `Foo`, only closures - arguments of the `Bar::new()`

Comment: But `Foo` will be used in other places, to get ref need write `&foo.borrow()` - that's a lot. To solve the problem, may using `Fn`, not `FnMut`. Then `RefCell` will be within `Foo`, but all methods must be called using `&self` - this crutch will be visible in the user API.....

Comment: The second example is not suitable, because will be other objects that will need to be edited in callbacks. I think that the function signature is `fn bar(pattern: Foo, ..)`, i.e. `struct Foo(u32); fn bar(Foo(x): Foo) { println!("{}", x) }` is completely correct. But in the method syntax `self` is reserved. All of the following are true: `fn bar(self: Self)`, `fn bar(self: &mut Self)`, `fn bar(mut self: &mut Self)`, `fn bar(self: Box<Self>)`...  Why work with `Box`? Maybe to this pattern will turn unsafe magic? Or hide `RefCell`?

Comment: In method syntax `&mut` self makes borrowing. The std has a trait `std::borrow::BorrowMut`, which theoretically is possible to implement, but I failed spoof lifetime.

Comment: It seems I can do nothing more to help. You would be better to create a new code example that better reflects your problem. Or create a new question linked to this.